# Spring Boot Micrometer to Azure Appinsights Collects Under the Same Namespace

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops, appinsights

Is there a way to change the *Custom Namespace* name in a Spring Boot app when using MS Application Insights?

I have a Spring Boot application deployed in Azure Devops with the appinsights runtime as a dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have the insights config set as Application config, specifically these:

- APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
- APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
- APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ROLE_NAME
- ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION (because of a known MS bug)

According to MS documentation, Micrometer metrics are gathered automatically. Which happens, but...

In my business logic I have a few Micrometer counters (`Counter metricCounter = Metrics.counter("metric-name");`) for monitoring and all metrics are available in the Application Insights service, including Tomcat and JVM metrics. Problem here is that *all* Spring Boot metrics are gathered under the Custom Namespace `azure.applicationinsights`. This is becoming a mess really fast as several apps are logging to the same Custom Namespace. Is there a way to set a namespace on an application level for a Spring Boot app?

In C# equivalent apps, we've used `new MetricTelemetry("metric-name"){ MetricNamespace = customNamespace}` to set a namespace for metrics which separates the custom metrics in Application Insights. But same here, would love to see it on an application level.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out, you can't. The Azure Java libraries don't fully support Micrometer as of now. This is requested and will be available in a future release of AppInsights for Java.
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/3027

Until released, Telemetry libs must be used to get a clear separation between apps.